# SQL Server without Powershell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 Express Edition, and it's demanding Windows Powershell and refusing to proceed with the installation. Is there any way to get it to install without Powershell? (The reason I'm asking is not so much for myself personally as to reduce the number of headaches through which I'm going to have to drag other people when I tell them my program needs SQL Server.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the command line install, i imagine you will be doing this for the sql server to set it up without the user going through it.

command line sql server 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(SQL.100).aspx

powershell
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_Windows_PowerShell_1.0#Performing_a_Windows_Server_2008_PowerShell_Command_Line_Installation

you can do these in silent mode and include the script run in install shield (or most installation package managers)

You doing the installations via script removes many headaches and if scripts fail, then have them sebd install log to find problem.

Answer (score 1):

Given that Powershell is part of the current windows operationg system - just install it. Actually, just install the current version of the perating system. Both Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 7 come with Powershell enabled (at least I find it on mine, and I know I did not include them manually or in the build images).

So, this basically is a non-issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

You will likely find that you don't want to not install powershell.  I believe in sql 2008 R2 there are management functions that require powershell.